# Use a PNG as a background image in MFC window

Tags: c++, image, background, mfc

I developed a small program in MFC that can display shapes and move them around.

I would like to be able to select PNG images that can be used as the background of the the main MFC window.

Currently, the background is set to black in the following code:

```
...
    CBrush brush;
    brush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
    myCDC->FillRect(r,&brush);
...
```

I've found classes that might allow me to upload Bitmaps - for example `[CStatic][1]` - but have had no luck finding something for PNGs.

Does anyone know how to do this, or have you ever done something similar?

Comment: Both CImage and native GDI+ can load PNG images

Comment: Best approach is GDI+ as it more versatile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533797%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Offhand I can think of [CxImage](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cximage/), [Libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html), and [GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798.aspx).

Comment: The easiest solution: Use a ListView and set it's background image. ListView's support GIF, PNG, JPG. Reference: [Uncommon Controls](http://www.luigibianchi.com/uncommon_controls.htm).

Comment: the OLE image class can handle PNGs, as I recall. check out "OleLoadImagePath" or whatever it was called, and family. after loading it's then an ordinary bitmap (as i recall).

Comment: @Cheers There is no `OleLoadImagePath`. This question is about displaying the image, not just loading it. If it's only about loading different image file formats use the [Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the class Image of Gdiplus
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534462(v=vs.85).aspx

because the png file can have the alpha property, but the bitmap does not have,
so I always use the Image to load the png file.

```
wchar_t szFile[256] = {0};   //  png image file path
Image*  m_pImage;
m_pImage = new Image(szFile, FALSE);   // Load png file


// drawing png image 
CPaintDC dc(this); // 用于绘制的设备上下文
Graphics graphics(dc.m_hDC);
if(m_pImage != NULL && (m_pImage->GetLastStatus() == Gdiplus::Status::Ok))
{
    graphics.DrawImage(m_pImage, 0, 0, m_pImage->GetWidth(), m_pImage->GetHeight());
}

// need delete it, if you donot need it
if (m_pImage != NULL)
{
    delete m_pImage;
    m_pImage = NULL;
}
```

Comment: CPaintDC dc(this); // 用于绘制的设备上下文
Graphics graphics(dc.m_hDC); m_hDC is a member variable of CDC.

Comment: Which `Image` class are you using?

Comment: class "Image" in the GdiPlus

Comment: 32bit ARGB bitmaps with an alpha channel are fully supported. See [Alpha Blending a Bitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183353.aspx) for an example. `CPaintDC` can only be used in your `OnPaint` handler for the `WM_PAINT` message. Do not ever use it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think that GDI+ is the best and simple way for display images. It supports jpg, gif, tiff as well as png.
You can just display a image as below code,

```
void OnPaint(HDC hdc)
{
   Graphics G(hdc);
   Image I(L"snowman.jpg");

   if (I.GetLastStatus() != Ok) {
     MessageBox(hWndMain,TEXT("cannot read the image file"), TEXT("error"),MB_OK);
     return;
   }
   G.DrawImage(&I,0,0);
}
```

Also, you can change image during execution time using `FromFile` static method.

```
Image *pI;
pI=Image::FromFile(L"snowman.jpg");

G.DrawImage(pI,0,0);

delete pI;
```